# Dilimit an input file which has "||" as a delimiter in PIG

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2, bigdata

I might be asking a naive question here, but i have just started learning PIG. I am working on an input file which has a data which is separated by ||. 
I have tried using PigStorage('||') and many other options close to it but none of them  worked.
Just wondering is there any other way or inbuilt type to separate the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Load it into a single field line:chararray and then use STRSPLIT on line with '||' as the splitter

Comment: PigStorage only works with single byte character as a delimiter (https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html)